# Управление звуком WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Возникла такая проблема, надо управлять звуком на странице, которая открыта в webView. Полностью убирать звук (mute), или же просто изменять.
Но как это сделать, я не нашел. Единственное решение которое я сейчас знаю, это управлять звуковым потоком самого устройства. Но мне это не очень нравится. Так же есть проблема, что при свертывании приложения звук остается. Хотя сама webView останавливается командой
web_view.onPause()
Очень надеюсь, что кто-то подскажет как это реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго экспериментируя я нашел решение своей проблемы.

```
private var bundleWebView = Bundle()

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    web_view.saveState(bundleWebView) // сохраняем состояние webView
    if(!bundleWebView.isEmpty)  web_view.loadUrl("") 
    // загружаем пустую страницу для прекращения воспроизведение
}

 override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
   
    if(!bundleWebView.isEmpty) {
        web_view.restoreState(bundleWebView) // восстанавливаем состояние webView 
    }
    else web_view.onResume()
}
```

Считаю это диким костылем, но другого решения пока не нашел. Может кого-нибудь это натолкнет на лучшее решение

Answer (score 1):

Здесь еще неизвестно это конкретный сайт или речь идет про любой. Если html заранее известен то можно попробовать останавливать/убирать звук в плеере через js, например `wv.loadUrl("javascript:{your js}");` [пример js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13369049/7540461) . Ну а так только с помощью `audioManager`

```
public static void mute(Context context) {
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int mute_volume = 0;
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mute_volume, 0);
}
public static void unmute(Context context) {
    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int unmute_volume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, unmute_volume, 0);
}
```

Так же ряд решений для проблемы при свертывании представлены на **en stack** -
[здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230902/7540461)

Comment: Сайт один, но к сожелению javascript тут не поможет. Уже думал об этом. 
Для меня очень странно, что в webView нет такого функционала. 
В любом случае спасибо большое